# Could i use k2 instead of joomla core articles?

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I use joomla for my websites but there is not a good commenting component for joomla ( i used jcomment but i don't like it). my last website is a blogging site for an ecommerce site, so i decide to use k2 for its blog section but last release of k2 is for last year.

my 2 reasons for using k2 over joomla's core articles are 1: built-in commenting system, 2: overriding layouts in k2 is simpler than joomla.

now i sould use joomla's core articles for blogging or k2? or even i should switch to wordpress (i didn't use wp before)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sole purpose of your website is blogging, then you should move to wordpress. Wordpress is easy so you should not have any major problem. Watch a few youtube videos and you will be able to get started.

Make sure you enable akismet spam protection for wordpress.